# Problem with multiple simple HTML Play/Pause buttons on one page

Tags: html, audio

That sounds like flowers :D

ANYway... so I have just added two sets of very simple HTML play and pause buttons on the one page, each set assigned to play a different MP3 file. The problem is that no matter what I do, both sets of buttons only refer to the last track mentioned. They are both controlling the same MP3 file even though I have named them differently. In this case both sets of buttons can play or pause 2.mp3, and they ignore 1.mp3  ..... what's going on here anyone, and how can I fix this?

```
<td>
<audio id="track1"><source src="tracks/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button" style="background-color:black; border-color:#666666; color:#FFFF66"><font size="3" face="Arial, sans-serif" color="#FFFF66">&nbsp;<strong>&#9658;</strong></button></font>&nbsp;<button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button" style="background-color:black; border-color:#666666; color:#FFFF66"><font size="3" face="Arial, sans-serif" color="#FFFF66">&nbsp;<strong>II</strong>&nbsp;</font></button> 
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("track1"); 
function playAudio() { 
  x.play(); 
} 
function pauseAudio() { 
  x.pause(); 
} 
</script>
</td>

<td>
<audio id="track2"><source src="tracks/2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button" style="background-color:black; border-color:#666666; color:#FFFF66"><font size="3" face="Arial, sans-serif" color="#FFFF66">&nbsp;<strong>&#9658;</strong></button></font>&nbsp;<button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button" style="background-color:black; border-color:#666666; color:#FFFF66"><font size="3" face="Arial, sans-serif" color="#FFFF66">&nbsp;<strong>II</strong>&nbsp;</font></button> 
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("track2"); 
function playAudio() { 
  x.play(); 
} 
function pauseAudio() { 
  x.pause(); 
} 
</script>
</td>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "even though I have named them differently"? You named them both `x`.

Comment: I guess to you its obvious. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is that you are assigning two different elements to one variable, so the last assignment is valid and only the second element is handled.**

You can use the following modification, making the element to be managed parametric, get used to working this way with duplicate CSS for example.

```
<td>
   <audio id="track1">
      <source src="tracks/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   </audio>
   <button onclick="playAudio('track1')" type="button" style="background-color:black; border-color:#666666; color:#FFFF66"><font size="3" face="Arial, sans-serif" color="#FFFF66">&nbsp;<strong>&#9658;</strong></button></font>&nbsp;<button onclick="pauseAudio('track1')" type="button" style="background-color:black; border-color:#666666; color:#FFFF66"><font size="3" face="Arial, sans-serif" color="#FFFF66">&nbsp;<strong>II</strong>&nbsp;</font></button> 
</td>
<td>
   <audio id="track2">
      <source src="tracks/2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   </audio>
   <button onclick="playAudio('track2')" type="button" style="background-color:black; border-color:#666666; color:#FFFF66"><font size="3" face="Arial, sans-serif" color="#FFFF66">&nbsp;<strong>&#9658;</strong></button></font>&nbsp;<button onclick="pauseAudio('track2')" type="button" style="background-color:black; border-color:#666666; color:#FFFF66"><font size="3" face="Arial, sans-serif" color="#FFFF66">&nbsp;<strong>II</strong>&nbsp;</font></button> 
</td>
<script>
   function playAudio(id) { 
     document.getElementById(id).play(); 
   } 
   function pauseAudio(id) { 
     document.getElementById(id).pause(); 
   } 
</script>
```

Comment: Fantastic Nicola thank you. Even though this is very basic coding it was beyond me. I understand now (I think) that "var" is a variable and I assigned them both to "x". Your code is even more efficient than doing them separately! Muchas Gracias!!